# Nodemon installation failed due to Unexpected end of JSON input Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, nodemon

I tried with `npm install nodemon` but got following error:

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
> '...-1.1.4.tgz","fileCoun'

Comment: Your package.json file contains invalid JSON, fixing the JSON would fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running

```
"npm cache clean --force"
```

and then try reinstalling nodemon package

Comment: npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.
the cache gets corrupted with some conflicting versions of different dependencies